# Problema con Javascript Fetch y Python

Tags: javascript, python, fetch

Recientemente comencé a programar en Python y tengo el siguiente problema. Simplifiqué el código lo más posible:

Código Javascript:

```
fetch ('ScriptPython.py')
.then (R => R.text ())
.then (R => console.log (R))
```

Código Python (archivo ScriptPython.py):

```
#!C:/Python39/python.exe
print ('Content-Type:text/plain\n')
from socket import gethostname
print (gethostname ())
```

Mi problema es que cuando pruebo el fetch en cualquier PC de mi red local siempre me devuelve el nombre de mi servidor. Necesito que me devuelva el nombre de la PC en que se ejecuta. Uso Windows 10 y XAMPP en mi servidor. Con PHP no tengo problemas, pero quiero hacerlo en Python.

Saludos y disculpen mi ignorancia. Es que soy nuevo en Python.

NOTA: Quiero evitar en lo posible el uso de frameworks (Django, Flask, etc) ya que quiero aprender primero el 'código puro'. De lo contrario si solo se puede hacer con un framework igual recibiré gustosamente la respuesta.

Comment: Pues si ejecutas `python ScriptPython.py` te debe de dar el nombre de la PC, lo que haces está bien

Comment: Ya lo probé de esa forma e igualmente me muestra el nombre del servidor. Es como si gethostname siempre devolviera el nombre del equipo donde se ejecuta el intérprete de Python. Saludos.

Comment: pues así es....

Comment: Esto sí lo puedo hacer con PHP, pero yo quería migrar mi back-end a Python. Por un lado, PHP responde casi instantáneamente y Python se me demora un segundo en responder debido a que tiene que llamar al intérprete. Pero por otro lado, Python en sí mismo es más seguro que PHP y el módulo smtplib está estupendo para enviar correo.

Comment: Quizás debería quedarme con PHP y ejecutar con shell-exec los no muchos scripts Python que necesito e investigaré más sobre cómo mejorar la seguridad en PHP. Al fin y al cabo, el 75% de mis operaciones en back-end son consultas MySQL. Uso las consultas preparadas de PDO para ello.

Comment: Pues simplemente utiliza flash o django o haz algo más básico con jinja

Comment: Sé que estoy en un error, pero no me gusta usar frameworks. Prefiero reinventar la rueda escribiendo mi propio código por que tengo confianza y control total de lo que hago. No me conformo con saber que una función de Django hace algo y ya. Quiero saber como lo hace. A la mayoría de mis colegas desarrolladores les sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Eso está excelente, pero como que algo de aquí no esta bien, no he trabajado mucho con cosas de web en python, pero sockets lo conozco muy bien. Por eso no puedo ayudar del todo aquí.